# Does USB mass-storage class requires re-enumeration after timeout?

Tags: arm, usb, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, usb-mass-storage

this might be a stupid question,

I was debugging a USB storage device on an ARM-CortexM4 platform (STM32F4 series) which runs embedded Linux. The ARM is working as USB host, and tries to communicate with a thumb drive in USB full speed (12Mb/s).

Now here is the problem. After successful enumeration and several SCSI commands thru BULK transfers, the capacity and everything can be read correctly. However, after about 15 seconds when I try to send these SCSI commands again (under same condition), the USB host controller just returns 'Transaction Error', which looks like the device is not responding to BULK transfers anymore (not ACKing) and the host controller times out. The question is, is there any timeout mechanism for USB mass-storage class or SCSI system such that, after a timeout the system must be re-enumerated or re-probed, otherwise it won't respond anymore?

I understand this might be due to a stupid error in my program, or due to some limitations on the specific hardware. However when I used usbmon module in Linux on a PC to capture the transfers on the very same thumb drive, I can see the operating system actually sends a sequence probing command (Read-max-Lun followed by Test-unit-ready) every 5 sec, which could be the reason why the thumb drive doesn't fail on my PC.

Thanks! I'm looking forward to any replies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with the Test Unit Ready commands.. I am in the middle of writing a mass storage device driver for an embedded device and When testing on OS X, after the initial SCSI queries, my device receives Test Unit Ready command about once every second when no other activity is occurring. Since your post is quite old, I recommend you post your own solution if you've since solved your problem.

Otherwise try adding periodic test unit ready commands from the host side when there is no other activity.. You could set and activate a timer whenever USB activity is occurring. If the timer fires, u can send a Test unit ready command.. Rinse repeat.

Comment: I appreciate your reply. Unfortunately, this problem hasn't been solved for some time and I have gave it up for now. I once tried to switch back to the USB Host firmware that was provided by STMicro and it seemed to be working, however I tried to copy everything into my Linux device driver and it hangs the device after several seconds as it did before.

Comment: My problem might be different from yours since I'm debugging the host and you are designing a device. I don't know who should send the periodic Test Unit Ready. Obviously it is not sent anywhere inside the Linux kernel drivers themselves automatically, so I suspect it is sent by some user space daemons such as udev? I'm not very familiar with user space programs, this is only a guess. Hope any expert in this can help me out. Thanks!